# is it okay in the many to many field table relation added field again?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

so i have relation table like this

Table department

```
id_department     type of office    salary
101               Pimpinan          1425000
102               Ka Mantri         850000
103               Kasir             650000
104               Staff Admin       525000
105               Mantri            500000
106              Mantri(Baru)        1000000
```

Table allowance

```
id_allowance     type of benefits    
1                 Jabatan           
2                 Kesehatan         
3                 Beras             
4                 Tunjagnan Prestasi        
5                 Tunjagan Sirkulasi           
6                 Tunjangan Do
```

many to many table

```
id   id_departement    id_allowance      cost benefit
1        101             1                  200000
2        101             2                  80000
3        101             3                  250000
4        101             4                  1200000
```

The question is it okay in many to many tables we add more field? the added field is cost benefit, This addition of the field I do, to reduce redundancy on the allowance table because in the tenure table each post has many allowances in the allowance table

thx you for attention

Comment: *"is it okay in the many to many field table relation added field again?"* This question is primarily opinion-based which is more or less oftopic..

Comment: There is no need for `id` in a many:many table.  Simply have `PRIMARY KEY(id_departement, id_allowance), INDEX(id_allowance, id_departement)`.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 2):

> The question is it okay in many to many tables we add more field?

Absolutely.  Many-to-many tables are often entities in their own right.  For instance:

- "orders" tables represent a many-to-many relationship between customers and products and often have order dates and other information.
- "doctors visits" represent a many-to-many relationship between doctors and patients and often have dates and other information.
- "page views" represent a many-to-many relationship between users and pages and often have dates and other information.

This is a common scenario, actually.